# TSQL odd duplicate row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am getting some odd duplicate rows in a TSQL query. Right now it is possible for an employee to have two credentials so those duplicates are ok, I will take care of that when I add credential priority, but what I am failing to understand is why this query is generating near duplicate rows when the data in the mro column is both 0 and 1 which should not be possible with the data.

Query

```
    Select  
  DISTINCT v.clientvisit_id,
  (case when v.non_billable=0 then v.duration else 0 end) / 60 as billable_hours,
  (case when (v.non_billable=0 AND Z_ServiceLedger.payer_id=63) then v.duration else 0 end) / 60 as billable_mro_hours,
  Credentials.credentials
From Z_ServiceLedger
  Inner Join ClientVisit v On Z_ServiceLedger.clientvisit_id =
    v.clientvisit_id
  Left Join Employees On v.emp_id = Employees.emp_id
  Left Join EmployeeCredential On Employees.emp_id = EmployeeCredential.emp_id
  Left Join Credentials On Credentials.credential_id =
    EmployeeCredential.credential_id
WHERE v.rev_timein >= @param1 And v.rev_timein < DateAdd(d, 1, @param2) And
    Z_ServiceLedger.amount > 0 AND
    v.splitprimary_clientvisit_id is null and
    v.gcode_primary_clientvisit_id is null and
    v.rev_timein <= 
    CASE WHEN EmployeeCredential.end_date is not null
        THEN EmployeeCredential.end_date
        ELSE GETDATE()
    END AND
     v.non_billable  = 0 and
    v.duration / 60 > 0 and
    (EmployeeCredential.is_primary is null or EmployeeCredential.is_primary != 'False') and
    v.client_id != '331771 ' and
    v.non_billable = 'FALSE'
GROUP BY Credentials.credentials, v.non_billable, v.duration, Z_ServiceLedger.payer_id, v.clientvisit_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY v.clientvisit_id
```

Sample output

```
clientvisit_id      billable_hours      billable_mro_hours      credentials  
921094  1   0   AS

921094  1   0   Res Tech

921094  1   1   AS
```

Comment: There are NO duplicates in the output shown.

Comment: No duplicates in the output. Note that DISTINCT does not only apply to `v.clientvisit_id` but to the whole row of result as a whole.

Comment: There must a row for `921094` that meets this condition, and another row that does not `when (v.non_billable=0 AND Z_ServiceLedger.payer_id=63) then v.duration else 0`

Comment: @AaronDietz Thanks, it did turn out there were some duplicate service ledgers and I've been able to filter based on ledger type.

Comment: Also if anyone knows how to set up a priority so that only the highest level credential is retained in the output that would be useful information.

Comment: NP.. and I'd ask another question for that, it's unlikely your comment will get much visibility.  You'll want to include the hierarchy of the credentials.